# Adobe Edge Animate—how do I get the current label?

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe-edge

In Adobe Edge Animate, how do I get the name of the label that corresponds to a given time? I've seen that I can get the current time as an integer using

```
sym.getPosition()
```

but if there's a label at that position, how do I get the label as a string?

Answer (score 4):

```
function getLabel() {

 var stage = sym.getComposition().getStage();
 var labels = stage.timelines['Default Timeline'].labels;

 var currentLabel;
 var currentPosition = stage.getPosition();

 $.each( labels, function( label, position ){
  if (position <= currentPosition) currentLabel = label;
 });

 return currentLabel;

}

console.log( getLabel() );
```

this will return the label on (or next previous to) the current position.

Comment: +1'ed this answer but I think the better solution may be to rework the question and compare the value of stage.getLabelPosition([label name]) with stage.getCurrentPosition() (in this case).  One wouldn't necessarily need to know the position of a label within logic blocks, you'd probably just want to know if the current position has a particular label.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us here looking for a Adobe Animate 2019 solution (like I was), it's similar, but slightly different:

```
function getLabel(_this) {

     var currentLabel;
     var currentPosition = _this.currentFrame;

     _this.labels.forEach(function( label, index ){
        if (label.position <= currentPosition) currentLabel = label.label;
     });

     return currentLabel;

}
```

Your position on the timeline is easier to get, and the labels object is organized differently. (Also jQuery is unavailable.)